# how can I change an element of array in arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am wondering how can I change an element of array in arraylist.
this is the example code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    ArrayList<String[]> arr = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String[] b = {"red", "green", "blue"};
    String[] c = {"banana", "apple", "orange"};
    String[] d = {"car", "motorcycle", "airplane"};
    String[] s = {"a","b","c"};

    arr.add(b);
    arr.add(c);
    arr.add(d);


    for(int i=0; i<arr.size();i++){
    System.out.println(arr.get(i)[1]);
        if (i==1) {
            arr.set(i, s);
        }
    }
    for (String[] strArr : arr) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArr));
    }


}
```

result of this code is

```
green
apple
motorcycle
[red, green, blue]
[a, b, c]
[car, motorcycle, airplane]
```

But actually I want to change only "apple" to "b", 
that is, [banana, b, orange].
so I made this code like this.

```
    for(int i=0; i<arr.size();i++){
        System.out.println(arr.get(i)[1]);
        if (i==1) {
            arr.set((i)[1], s);
        }
    }
```

this one, however, it makes error.

I found that get and set both needs int index on developer document, 
Arraylist.get(int index) and Arraylist.set(int index, E element).

I can't understand why get(i)[1] is okay but set(i)[1],s is not allowed.
is there any other syntax that I can access one element to array in arraylist?

Comment: You're not setting an element of the list, so you don't use set. You get an array out of the list (using get) and then assign an element (using `[]`).

Answer (score -1):

try the following. `arr.set((i)[1], s);` is no valid java.

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.size();i++){
  System.out.println(tmp);
  if (i==1) { // if ListIndex == 1
    String[] tmp = arr.get(i); // get Array at ListIndex i and store it in tmp
    tmp[1] = s[1]; // set Item at Postion 1 in tmp to Item at Position 1 in Array s;
    arr.set(i, tmp); // set Array at ListIndex i to tmp
  }
}
```

`get(i)[1]` is allowed because `get(i)` returns an array and `[1]` is a valid index for the returned array. in `set((i)[1], ...)`  i is an integer and `[1]` not defined on an integer.

Comment: `arr.get(i)[1] = s[1]` is much faster. No need to set the array again.

Comment: I know. But the asker didn't asked about the fastet solution. I want to explain the concept, so explained it in single steps.